# How do I stop keyframes from other rigs from showing up in the Dope Sheet?

Tags: animation, interface, dopesheet

I'm working on actions that use multiple rigs, for example a character has a rig for their body and a separate rig for their hair. While attempting to work on the animation for one rig, the dope sheet insists on cluttering up the window with ALL keyframes for ALL the other rigs, even though those rigs are hidden.

I have "Only show selected" enabled, it only obeys that command for the current visible rig, the invisible rigs will continue to show even though they are both hidden and NOT selected.

For example here:

[image: example of the problem]

The Head bone (and only the head bone) is selected and correctly visible, yet the Hair bones for the *entire* hair rig are always visible, even while the hair rig is hidden and unselected. This behavior will switch if I select the hair rig; making EVERY keyframe in the body rig fill up the window while I have to hunt for the channel I am trying to animate in the current rig.

I feel like I am missing some obvious toggle to hide this workflow crippling clutter that I just can't find in the UI.